# Projectivization of normal bundle of a smooth variety in projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X \subset \mathbb P^N$ be a smooth variety. Using Grothendieck notation, it is well-known that the conormal variety
$$
\mathbb P(N_{X|\mathbb P^N}(-1))
$$
has two projections: $p_1$ to $X$ and $p_2$ to the dual variety $X^*$. I am interested in the case of "co-conormal variety"
$$\tag{$\star$}
\mathbb P(N^*_{X|\mathbb P^N}(a)).
$$
In particular, I want to understand the projection $p_2$ not to $X$. Moreover, when $X$ is a self-dual variety listed by Ein and Snow ($X=Q^n,\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^{n-1},G(\mathbb P^1, \mathbb P^4), S_{10}$), I can prove using the machinery of $\mathbb C^*$-action on rational homogeneous spaces that the image via $p_2$ is a variety $Y$ that parametrize the family of maximal quadrics contained in $X$ ($Y=\text{a point},G(\mathbb P^1, \mathbb P^{n-1}),(\mathbb P^4)^*, Q^8$).

In order to understand if this property is given or not by the self-duality, I am looking for some results about $(\star)$.

Any hint or reference will be appreciate